# How to get all data from multi dimesnion object array when it changes all the time

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

At start i made html table for specific xml array, 
it worked.But then i tested my code on others and it failed read all levels :(
here are 2 arrays that try to access manually

```
$newaCref->Debts->LiabilityDebts[$i]->Debt->Sum[$b]->Total

$newaCref->Debts->LiabilityDebts[$k]->Debt[$j]->Sum->Total
```

to access them first parts `$newaCref->Debts->LiabilityDebts` are the same but then it changes and goes even deeper.

My question is how to make it go automatically through all levels i need?

This is how i do it now for each `<td>` row and `$newaCref` is result of XML

```
$newaCref = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldataC, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
for($i=0;$i<count($newaCref->Debts->LiabilityDebts);$i++){
    for($b=0;$b<count($newaCref->Debts->LiabilityDebts[$i]->Debt->Sum);$b++){
        foreach($newaCref->Liabilities->Liability[$i]->Sum[$b]->Total as $row){
        echo '<td>'.$row.'</td>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a bit of recursion going on my man

Comment: Better use `simplexml_*` & `xpath()` to access subnodes from an XML Object. http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: And to be helpful, we would need to know more about the data structure you are processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly what more info is needed?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions i use new SimpleXMLElement($xmldataC, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

Comment: Well a look at the XML might be useful.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i cant do it :(

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is my HUGE XML http://pastebin.com/StUaZc3Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not testet, just to explain:

```
 $newaCref = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldataC, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
 $result = $xml->xpath('/Debts/LiabilityDebts');

 while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    $subresult = $node->xpath('Debt/Sum');
    while(list( , $subnode) = each($subresult)) {
        echo '<td>'.((string)$subnode).'</td>';
    }
 }
```

Notes:

In your example the inner `foreach` makes no sence at this point.

`$newaCref->Liabilities->Liability[$i]`

The `xpath` for this would be `/Liabilities/Liability`

If you are showing `$xmldataC` in your example, why are you saying `@RiggsFolly i cant do it :(` and not just do `print_r(htmlentities($xmldataC))`?

So take this as example and get it work for your needs. But keep in mind, xml can be tricky if you dont now how they work, especially in PHP.

:)

Comment: Hi i tried your code it not working (showing empty array) yet for me but i m trying :) here is XML http://pastebin.com/StUaZc3Z

Comment: i need to return 2 tables one with LiabilityDebts other with Liabilities

Comment: i just need to learn this once next time it would be much easy

Comment: I got your code working but having problem getting other data!Table messed up

Comment: @Ingus Graholskis Was away. If you got something working and got stuck again reopen a new question for it :)